# she has had to struggle

Tags: grammar

*Since her childhood she has had to struggle with serious illness.*

In the above sentence the present perfect of the modal verb is used. I would like to ask whether the continuous form is possibe.

Comment: Yes, *"...she's been having to struggle..."* is grammatically correct, but I can't imagine such a cumbersome structure being common

Comment: Normally the -ing would be attached to the lexical verb rather than to the auxiliary: *She's been struggling with serious illness since childhood.*

Comment: What do you mean "the present perfect of the modal verb"?  I don't see any modal auxiliary here.

Answer (score 1):

Since her childhood she has been struggling with serious illness.

I would avoid the double has/had if possible because it can be confusing.
I would even re-write the first sentence as: Since her childhood she has struggled with serious illness.